# Unable to Pause Activity due to Null Pointer Exception on String Array List

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, onpause

I have a string array list in my app, which contains data pulled off from a website in the main activity. I am using `onPause()` to save the size and data in this array list so that if the user navigates back to this activity, the data persists.

As of now, if an item in the list is clicked, it opens up the new activity as expected. The hard press 'back' key also navigates back to the main activity, with the list contents displayed, again as I want it. However, from here, if I click any list item, the app crashes. Logcat mentions `NullPointerException` with regard to my array list with the error `'Unable to Pause Activity'`.

My code:

**For onPause()**

```
protected void onPause(){
     super.onPause();
     SharedPreferences preferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     SharedPreferences.Editor sEdit=preferences.edit();
     sEdit.putInt("size",headlinessize);
    for(int i=0;i<headlinessize-1;i++)
    {
         sEdit.putString("link"+i,links.get(i));    
        sEdit.putString("head"+i, headlines.get(i));

    }

     sEdit.commit();

}
```

**For onCreate()**

```
             SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    headlinessize=preferences.getInt("size",0);
    for(int j=0;j<headlinessize-1;j++)
    {
              headlines.add(preferences.getString("head"+j,null));
              links.add(preferences.getString("link"+j,null));
    }
```

I get the error with the `headlines` array list!

How is it that `onPause()` works perfectly the first time, and crashes the app on any subsequent item click?

Some additional information:

I am connecting to the internet on a separate thread, pulling data off a site, passing this data to a handler which updates my string array list. It also updates the size of the array list in a separate variable `headlinessize`. Also `headlines` and `links` are string array lists of the same size.

Thanks!

Comment: kindly check if ur object is null before retriving ur size

Comment: Also, post a stack trace.

Comment: I checked both the contents of `headlines` and `links` lists. Both retain data when the main activity is returned to. Also, I noted that it 'crashes'(doesnt close) only on the 2nd attempt to click a list item. After that it opens the activity again, as if the app is opened afresh.

It appears both lists are populated appropriately. But it still springs up a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: What are you doing on the `onResume()` ? When you go back to your main activity the `onResume()` will be evoked.

Comment: Ok. Isn't `onCreate()` enough?I included an onResume() code. However the same NullExceptionError occurs, now saying 'Can't Resume Activity'.